# How to change renderMode=direct in Flash Professional CS5.5?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs5.5

I need to change the render mode (wmode) to direct in Flash CS5.5, but I only get Auto, CPU or GPU mode. How can I edit the Name-app.xml to build the .ipa file with MY XML?
Thank you Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

this is the only current solution vie found - http://blog.michaeljbowen.com/?p=127#comment-1034

Comment: ahn, ok. It's a good solution. It's a hack and I think that in CS6 it is fixed, right?
Thank you for the link!